# Stop sound in Swift 5

Tags: xcode, audio, avfoundation, swift5

I'm trying to stop the sound by using .pause() func because I couldn't find .stop() func anywhere in the suggestion, is it fine??

```
func stopAlarm() {

    audio.pause()
}

func playAlarm() {

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Alarm", withExtension: "mp3")
    audio = AVPlayer.init(url: URL!)
    audio.play()      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's `pause()` which is the same as setting the property `rate` to 0.

e.g. `audio.rate = 0`